# In an ASP.NET MVC 3 intranet app, how to modify a view depending on user's AD group membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, authorization

In our ASP.NET MVC 3 intranet application, configured with `WindowsTokenRoleProvider` for authentication, users must be members of a certain AD group in order to access administrative content. We have solved this by applying `AuthorizeAttribute` to the administrative MVC controller. *However*, we haven't integrated the administrative content with the GUI menu system yet.

To this end, we'd like to add links to the administrative sections to the app menu, but for authorized users only. This brings us to the question at hand, how can we in the view template (*.cshtml) render content depending on whether the user is part of the required AD group or not?

Comment: Take a look at my MSDN article How to Create an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
                    {
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Approvals", "TeamIndex", "Leave")</li>
                    }
```

Comment: You should also keep in mind that this will only restrict users from seeing the link in your view. A user could still access your view by typing in the URL http://www.yoursite/Leave/TeamIndex . In order to prevent this, you should apply the authorize attribute to your Actions in your controller or on the controller itself.